# Fedora 32bit VM Virtualbox screen size does not cover my entire screen

Tags: eclipse, fedora

I have a fedora 32bit VM Virtualbox machine and when I try to choose the option for view->switch to full screen the display does not cover the whole screen.
Is there an option to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will need to install the guest editions in order to get the higher resolution . Here is a link https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html